# My jquery headline and PHP query

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery headline like this:

```
<div class="mainGallery">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="mainDesc">
      <h2> </h2>
      <a class="mainA" href="#"> </a> </div>
    <ul class="pg">
      <li> 1 <a href="#" rel="Headline Title 1"></a> <span rel="Headline Lorem1 ipsum dolor sit amet"></span>
        <p rel="images/1.jpg"></p>
      </li>
      <li> 2 <a href="#" rel="Headline Title 2"></a> <span rel="Headline Lorem ipsum2 dolor sit amet"></span>
        <p rel="images/2.jpg"></p>
      </li>
      <li> 3 <a href="#" rel="Headline Title 3"></a> <span rel="Headline Lorem ipsum3 dolor sit amet"></span>
        <p rel="images/3.jpg"></p>
      </li>
      <li> 4 <a href="#" rel="Headline Title 4"></a> <span rel="Headline Lorem ipsum4 dolor sit amet"></span>
        <p rel="images/4.jpg"></p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="mainImg"><img src=""/></div>
</div>
```

My jquery is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.pg li').click(function(){
    var header      = $(this).find('a').attr('rel');
    var desc        = $(this).find('span').attr('rel');
    var images      = $(this).find('p').attr('rel');
    $(".mainDesc h2").text(header);
    $(".mainDesc a").text(desc);
    $(".mainImg img").attr("src", images);
   }
);
 }

);
```

Everything is ok, But when refreshing the page, the first item is missed.
I want to insert only one mysql query in mainDesc. I want to first item will be shown with jquery not mysql query.
How can I fix this for showing first item when page refreshed.
Thanks

[When page refreshed http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/9201/79025058.jpg](http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/9201/79025058.jpg)
[When clicked http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/2926/25644092.jpg](http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/2926/25644092.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by "missed"? Where is a mySQL query referenced?

Comment: I have edited my question. When page refreshed, the content will be missed.  I want to first item will be shown when page refreshed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate a click on one of the `li`s after binding the onClick event, so the content is shown when the page is loaded. Add this after binding the click event

```
$(".pg li:first").click();
```

This will fire the onClick event on the first `li` element.

To make it faster you should also cache the `li` elements so yo don't have to look them up twice. The javascript would then look like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $lis = $(".pg li");
    $lis.click(function(){
        var $li = $(this);
        var $mainDesc = $(".mainDesc");

        var header      = $("a", $li).attr("rel");
        var desc        = $("span", $li).attr("rel");
        var images      = $("p", $li).attr("rel");

        $("h2", $mainDesc).html(header);
        $("a", $mainDesc).html(desc);
        $(".mainImg img").attr("src", images);
    });
    $lis.eq(0).click();

});
```

It also seems to me like you could switch from using "mainDesc" as a class to an ID, since it seems like there's only one mainDesc on the page.

---

You're also missing an ending `</div>` tag at the end of you HTML.

Comment: Speaking of cacheing, this could be taken a step further with $(this) being assigned to a var instead of calling $(this) all the time. Also with $(".mainDesc).find('h2').text(header).end().find('a').text(desc); On a note of reference, events can be triggered using the .trigger method also. $(elem).trigger('click');

Comment: For the enthusiasts, $li.find('a') is faster than $('a', $li) - http://ejohn.org/blog/talks-at-the-2009-jquery-conference/#comment-387081